# FullCalendar 4 - add and then access additional values to the Event Object

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

How do I add and then access additional values **My_Custom_Value** to the Event Object?

```
events: [
  {
    title: 'My Title',
    My_Custom_Value: 'some details',
    allDay: false,
    start: 1501056000000,
    end: 1501057800000
  }
],
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Access your value through "**extendedProps**":

A plain object holding miscellaneous other properties specified during parsing. Receives properties in the explicitly given extendedProps hash as well as other non-standard properties."

https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-object

```
eventRender: function(info){

                    console.log("_______ info _______\n");
                    console.log(info.event.extendedProps.My_Custom_Value);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use extendedProps. You can include them in the event object directly (https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-object), or add them afterwards using method Calendar::setExtendedProp (https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Event-setExtendedProp)

```
events: [
    {
        title: 'My Title',
        My_Custom_Value: 'some details',
        allDay: false,
        start: 1501056000000,
        end: 1501057800000
        extendedProps: {
            description: 'whatever',
            madeupProperty: 'banana'
        }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer to this is contained in the Event Parsing documentation at https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-parsing.

The way you're setting the custom property in your object is fine. As per that documentation, fullCalendar will read it, and then place it in the `extendedProps` property of the event object it creates internally.

So if you then need come to access that event later (e.g. via one of fullCalendar's callbacks such as `eventClick`, perhaps) you would use `event.extendedProps.My_Custom_Value` to access it.