How can I make fullcalendar event resizable and droppable customly
in fullcalendar how can I make if event.extendedProps.isBelong prop is true make event resizable and droppable but else disable them
eventRender: function (info) {
    var event = info.event;
    var element = info.el;

    var customContent = `
            <div class="fc-content">
                <div class="custom-event-content" style="cursor: initial;padding: .6rem;">
                    <small>${moment(event.start).format("HH:mm")} - ${moment(event.end).format("HH:mm")} </small><br/>
                    <a style="color: ${event.textColor};text-decoration: none;" href="${event.extendedProps.urlString}"><strong> ${event.title} </strong></a><br/>
                    <i class="fa-solid fa-eye pointer mt-2"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="fc-resizer fc-resizer-start"></div>
            <div class="fc-resizer fc-resizer-end"></div>
        `;

    element.innerHTML = customContent;


    var eyeIcon = element.querySelector('.fa-eye');
    console.log(eyeIcon)
    if (eyeIcon) {
        eyeIcon.addEventListener('click', function () {
            openDetailModal(info);
        });
    }
},


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Please confirm that you added isBelong as an extended property.  see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56918154/fullcalendar-4-add-and-then-access-additional-values-to-the-event-object

droppable is a property of the calendar (not the event). You can change calendar options after init via https://fullcalendar.io/docs/dynamic-options

Did you perhaps mean "make the event draggable" rather than droppable? Droppable only applies to items outside the calendar, which you can then drop onto the calendar (see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/droppable). Otherwise I don't think your question would make sense.

If you want to make an event draggable and resizable, you can set its editable  property as per https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-parsing. This would need to be done during eventDataTransform though (see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventDataTransform), not during rendering. If you can clarify that this is actually what you mean, I will post a proper answer with an example. If this is not what you mean, please [edit] your question to make it more clear. Thankyou.

P.S. Also, what version of fullCalendar are you using? eventRender hasn't existed since v4, but the current version is v6. Try to always use an up-to-date version if possible.
